# Do Beta Israel have Kohens?

Tags: kohen-priest, ethiopian-beta-israel

Does the Beta Israel community have Kohens? Are [Kahens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kahen) equivalent? If so, are they descended from Aaron?

Comment: It seems the Kahen is an appointed position, whereas proper Kehunah is genealogical (by birth).

Comment: @יהודה rather than significantly changing one user's question, wouldn't it have been better to ask your own?

Comment: @Harel13 Shalom, what I notice from my time spent on this particular Stack Exchange is that if you have a question that is similar in nature, it can be more prone to being closed.  So instead of just asking a new question and hoping that someone would answer this question (no one answered the questions in 8 Years),  I respectfully kept the essence of the question and only added made a slight addition (if they are recognized as being Priest) and explained not only why I, but also how I came to make that addition.

Comment: Today’s edit is dishonest. An editor has put works into mouth of another person.

Comment: @BSteinhurst Shalom, please elaborate?

Comment: @יהודה you have spoken in the original poster’s voice by using a first person narrative voice. The question now reads as if the original poster followed your train of discovery to come to this question. There is no evidence that this is the case.

Comment: @BSteinhurst so I'm guessing you didn't read when I wrote: "it led me to research and have a very similar question to the original post". Also if you check edits, you see very clearly (very clearly) whatever changes I personally made (even if one wanted to hide it they can't). But as long as you are here do you have any insight to the subject/question at hand?

Comment: @KinnardHockenhull Shalom beloved has the additions I made to your question disrespect or belittle your original intent when posing this question some time ago?

Comment: @יהודה the edits are not my words and do not reflect my intent: I was aware at the time of the asking of the question that Ethiopian Jews view Kebra Negast as a fabrication. And I am not as familiar with the narrative of Kebra Negast as your edits would make me seem. Though now I am very much more curious. Additionally it certainly wouldn't make sense for me to say that "I came across" a question which I myself would ask ~3 years later as that would necessitate time travel or something like that. So that goes beyond lacking evidence but is presumably impossible @ BSteinhurst 

Comment: @KinnardHockenhull If the way I phrase and augmented your post in any disingenuous manner, made others believe you stated anything that you did not, or beared any false witness in respect to you my sincere apologies.  Would you like for me to change anything or roll back to how you originally asked the question?

Comment: I rolled back already. Now I’m just thinking about the Aron Kodesh and time travel. There’s a lesson in everything?

Comment: Additionally I was unaware of the tradition that queen Judith was a Bat Kohen at the time of the asking of the question. It appears there was a conflict between the Ethiopian Kohanic and Judahite/Davidic lines. May try to dig up a source

Comment: @KinnardHockenhull That's good and very interesting. If you find anything in your research, please share if able :).

Comment: Time for the ark to time travel?

Answer (score 3):

The following [website](https://geneticliteracyproject.org/2015/10/06/cohanim-studies-understanding-the-ethiopian-beta-israel-jewish-priesthood-tradition/) writes as follows:

> Although the Beta Israel — the Ethiopian Jews, a minority of today’s Israeli population, who mostly came to the country in two waves in the 1980s and early 1990s—maintain the priesthood tradition, they are unique in that they do not consider it to be hereditary. Instead, the Beta Israel priest, called as Kes or Kahin (Cohen), is elected by his community. Traditionally, Keses, as [Ken Blady](https://rowman.com/ISBN/9780765761125/Jewish-Communities-in-Exotic-Places) explains, “were for the most part drawn from the general population, and each was selected based on his own merits” (p. 363).

So it would seem that unlike the Kohanim as we know it, which one is born into, their equivalent is something that is an appointed title.

Comment: Todah Rabbah for your response.  Have you come across any information about the Monk and others who are commissioned to protect and guard The Ark (In Ethiopia)? Such as their lineage, how they are chosen, the training they may go through to become said protectors/guardians?

Comment: @יהודה - have a look at this link which gives a very comprehensive academic overview: https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/41125331.pdf